# .NET Tasks and Dictionary - Writing too fast

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, dictionary, task

I'm using .NET Tasks to gain advantage of multi-threading but it's not so easy to implement.

Just to demonstrate the issue I'm having, I wrote a simplified version of my actual code.

After executing the code, you realize that the final AllResults dictionary does have KeyValuepairs of (Nothing, Nothing) - which is impossible to add.

After thinking a bit, I guess I found why it happens but I couldn't find a solution.

I guess that's happening because the sub-tasks are adding keyvaluepairs to main-level dictionary "AllResults" too fast - not allowing it to allocate more space when the dictionary reached it's size.
As far as I know, a dictionary resizes itself to double of current size when it gets full. But I guess due to using tasks (running on other threads), it gets more than double during resizing itself, which causes Nothing (null) elements.

.NET must be trying to prevent memory access error (probably bluescreen) by adding the element as (nothing,nothing) . Actually, this is a good behaviour and prove that how Dictionaries well-written in .NET. It could skip adding but we probably wouldn't know about the error which would cause to data-loss.

But, how to solve this issue?

Thanks by now.

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1

    Public AllResults As Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass) 'this is the issue

    Public Class SomeClass

        Public Property ID As Integer
        Public Property Name As String

        Public ADictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

        Public subClasses As Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass)

        Public Sub New()

        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub Main()

        AllResults = New Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass)

        Dim Classes As Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass) = New Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass)
        Classes.Add(10, New SomeClass With {.ID = 1, .Name = "10"})
        Classes.Add(20, New SomeClass With {.ID = 2, .Name = "20"})
        Classes.Add(40, New SomeClass With {.ID = 3, .Name = "40"})
        Classes.Add(80, New SomeClass With {.ID = 4, .Name = "80"})
        Classes.Add(160, New SomeClass With {.ID = 5, .Name = "160"})
        Classes.Add(320, New SomeClass With {.ID = 6, .Name = "320"})
        Classes.Add(640, New SomeClass With {.ID = 7, .Name = "640"})
        Classes.Add(1280, New SomeClass With {.ID = 8, .Name = "1280"})

        Dim MainTasks(Classes.Count - 1) As Task

        Dim MTX As Integer = 0

        Dim Depth As Integer = 3

        For Each sc As SomeClass In Classes.Values
            MainTasks(MTX) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                       DoCalculation(sc, Depth)
                                                   End Sub)
            MTX += 1
        Next

        Task.WaitAll(MainTasks)

        Console.WriteLine("Completed.")

        Dim IE As IOrderedEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, SomeClass))


        IE = AllResults.OrderBy(Function(v) v.Value.ID)


        For Each vkvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, SomeClass) In IE
        Next


        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub


    Public Function DoCalculation(inputClass As SomeClass, depth As Integer) As Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass)

        'do some work here

        Dim newID As Integer, newClass As SomeClass

        inputClass.subClasses = New Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass)

        For x As Integer = 10 To 20
            newID = Integer.Parse(inputClass.ID.ToString + x.ToString)
            newClass = CloneClass(inputClass)
            newClass.ID = newID
            inputClass.subClasses.Add(x, newClass)
        Next

        If depth > 0 Then

            Dim SubTasks(inputClass.subClasses.Count - 1) As Task
            Dim STX As Integer = 0

            For Each c As SomeClass In inputClass.subClasses.Values
                AllResults.Add(c.ID, c)
                SubTasks(STX) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                                                          DoCalculation(c, depth - 1)
                                                      End Sub, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
                STX += 1
            Next

            Task.WaitAll(SubTasks)

        End If

        Return inputClass.subClasses

    End Function

    Public Function CloneClass(inputClass As SomeClass) As SomeClass

        Dim newClass As SomeClass = New SomeClass

        newClass.Name = "Clone of " + inputClass.Name

        newClass.ADictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)(inputClass.ADictionary)

        Return newClass

    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dictionary` is not a thread-safe collection (by default all .NET objects are not, unless the documentation states otherwise).

This means that it is not programmed to work correctly when used from multiple threads concurrently.

You must either:

- Use a synchronization primitive such as a lock around all `AllResults` usages.
- Use a thread-safe collection, have a look in `System.Collections.Concurrent`.